SpringBoot 3.2.4: sleuth.reactor.instrumentation-type: decorate-queues replacement in micrometer
How to migrate/replace the below sleuth property in spring boot 3 with micrometer tracing?
sleuth:
  reactor:
    instrumentation-type: decorate-queues

The application is a webflux project
On doing the spring boot 3 migration, could not find a proper one on one mapping for the above property in micrometer tracing. Looking to find a replacement.
Previously, the application was using sleuth dependency.
<dependency> 
<groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> 
<artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId> 
</dependency> 

Currently, the below micrometer tracing dependencies are added.
<dependency> 
<groupId>io.micrometer</groupId> 
<artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave</artifactId> 
</dependency> 
<dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId> 
</dependency>


Previously, the application was using sleuth dependency.

org.springframework.cloud
spring-cloud-starter-sleuth

now the below micrometer tracing dependencies are added.

io.micrometer
micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-actuator


dont post part of the info into comments, update your question instead

TL;DR:
Depending on your needs and the Boot version you use, you can either:

Do nothing since there are some context propagation enabled by default
Set spring.reactor.context-propagation to AUTO
Use Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation() for older versions of Boot 3.x

I think you can get the behavior you want setting spring.reactor.context-propagation=AUTO.
Details:
Micrometer Tracing was born from the codebase of Spring Cloud Sleuth, but we removed the Spring bits, including the instrumentation, so that it can be used in any Java project. This means that the Reactor instrumentation (that lived in Spring Cloud Sleuth before) is now in Reactor. :)
You can read about the Context Propagation support in the Reactor docs. Also, I recommend this series of blog posts by Dariusz: Context Propagation with Project Reactor.
Boot offers auto-configuration and property support for this feature, you can read about it in the Observability section of the Spring Boot docs and  in the Appendix about spring.reactor.context-propagation.

Thanks for your reply Jonatan.
Im using Springboot 3.2.4 and I am trying to find a replacement for the existing instrumentation-types -DECORATE_QUEUES,DECORATE_ON_EACH,DECORATE_ON_LAST and MANUAL.
If I set the reactor.context-propagation to AUTO, which type it would be picking up?
I am looking for the exact replacement for DECORATE_QUEUES. Would it be DECORATE_QUEUES by default?

Neither but DECORATE_QUEUES might be the closest. The current mechanism of Reactor fixes the issues DECORATE_QUEUES had, if you are looking for the exact same thing, you need to implement that (with all the existing issues and bugs).

Thanks Jonatan. The suggested context-propagation solution worked for me.
